# How to show that $x^n\notin (xy-yx-1)$ inside $k\langle x,y\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

This may be a trivial question, but somehow I just can't seem to find an easy enough argument, and I lose myself in complicated constructions.

Let $k$ be a field and let $k\langle x,y\rangle$ be the free non-commutative, associative algebra on two generators. I would like to show that $x^n\notin (xy-yx-1)$, where $(xy-yx-1)$ is the two sided ideal generated by $xy-yx-1$. How to do so?

Comment: Probably you can consider a representation of this algebra. For example, consider polynomial algebra $k[t]$ and define linear operators $x$ and $y$ in the following way: $(x\cdot p)(t):=\frac{dp}{dt}$ and $(y\cdot p)(t):=t\cdot p(t)$ for any $p\in k[t]$. Then, it's easy to check that $xy-yx-1=0$ (1 here is the identity operator). Thus, you obtain the action of the quotient algebra $k\langle x,y\rangle/(xy-yx-1)$ on $k[t]$. Now it suffices to prove that $x^n$ is not a zero operator on $k[t]$.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't help if $n\geq \operatorname{char}(k)>0$, as then $x^n$ is the zero operator.

Comment: Is it possible to find full-rank matrices $A$, $B$ over an arbitrary field such that $AB - BA = I$?

Comment: No, since the trace of $I$ is not zero.

Comment: Oh, we are working over the field of positive $\operatorname{char}(k)$, sorry.

Comment: I think Etingof discusses this in the section 2.7. of his Introduction to representation theory, see http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/repb.pdf

Comment: The argument remains mostly the same but you need consider the representation of the Weyl algebra on more abstract object, namely $t^a k[a][t,t^{-1}]$.

Comment: Ah yes this is really useful (and ingenious), thanks!

Comment: OK, this comment might be a bit advanced -- but the ring of PD differential operators on $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ still satisfies $[D, t] = 1$ while we have $D^n \ne 0$ for every $n$.  (One way to describe this is as $k[t]$-linear functions on $k[t,u,(u-t)^2/2!,(u-t)^3/3!,\ldots]$ which are continuous w.r.t. the filter of ideals generated by $(u-t)^n/n!$, with a certain composition operation induced by $k[t,u,(u-t)^2/2!,\ldots] \to k[t,u,v,(v-u)^n/n!,(v-t)^n/n!,(u-t)^n/n!]$, $t \mapsto t, u \mapsto v, (u-t)^n/n! \mapsto (v-t)^n/n!$.)

Comment: Oh, or how about swapping the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the original example: $x := t\cdot$, $y := -\frac{d}{dt}$?

Comment: Though the ring of PD differential operators construction should generalize to show that *any* element of the form $\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty a_{ij} y^i x^j$ with finitely many $a_{ij} \ne 0$ is in the two-sided ideal generated by $xy-yx-1$ if and only if all $a_{ij} = 0$ (and also any element of the quotient can be written in that form, giving a fairly complete description of the quotient ring).